# Getting correct element from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have a DOM tree like this:

```
<div class="like-bttn" data-answer-id="{{answer.id}}">
  <div class="count>{{ answer.like_score }}</div>
  <div class="heart>&#10084;</div>
</div>
```

I have a javascript code to make ajax request when like-bttn clicked:

```
  $(".like-bttn").click(function(ev) {
    var id = $(ev.target).attr('data-answer-id');
    ... do something with id ...
  })
```

But when .heart is clicked my code does not work, becaouse ev.target is .heart and it does not have 'data-answer-id'

What is correct approach at this stiuation?

Comment: I recommend to read http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/ and the other events articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)`, not the event target  :

```
$(".like-bttn").click(function(ev) {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-answer-id');
   ... do something with id ...
 })
```

and, as Neal pointed, it's cleaner to use `data` :

```
  var id = $(this).data('answerId');
```

Comment: or: `$(this).data('answerId')`

Comment: jQuery changes the data element to camelCase. [[source](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)]

Comment: @Neal: It's actually not jQuery that does this (well maybe it does, but it's all in compliance with the specification): http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes.

Comment: @FelixKling please see the source in my comment. They are conforming to the W3C HTML5 specification.

Comment: i disagree with *"it's better to use `data`"*

Comment: @KevinB Why do you "disagree"?

Comment: Unless it's json and you want it to auto parse it to json, it's faster to just get the attribute value. due to the fact that .data will try to guess what kind of value it is and parse it, then store it internally when all you really need is the string value.

Comment: @Neal: That's what I'm saying! I just mean that jQuery might already get the attribute names in that format (depending on how the access them), so it might not be jQuery that does the conversion.